# How to handle image recycling in ViewPager fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, android-viewpager, picasso

I have an image viewer that uses ViewPager. Each fragment has a large-ish image on it. This works fine for a while, but after enough images, the app runs out of memory.

To fix this, I'm trying to recycle the bitmaps, but this causes another problem: If I swipe back, the recycled bitmap causes a `RuntimeException`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@268f7cd3
```

The fragment code looks like this:

```
Bitmap m_image = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);

    final ImageView img = (ImageView)root.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Picasso.with(getContext())
           .load(getArguments().getString("url"))
           .into(new Target()
           {
               @Override
               public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
               {
                   m_image = bitmap;
                   img.setImageBitmap(m_image);
                   img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }

               @Override
               public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable)
               {
               }

               @Override
               public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable)
               {
               }
           });

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    if(m_image != null)
    {
        m_image.recycle();
        m_image = null;
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

And the Activity that holds the ViewPager looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

    final DataHandler dataHandler = getApp().getDataHandler();

    PagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())
    {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            Entry e = dataHandler.get(position);
            Fragment f = new ImageFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("url", e.getURL());
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return dataHandler.getCount();
        }
    });

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vpImages);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to handle the memory when using Picasso. If your Fragments are GCed the ImageView will take care of recycling the Bitmap associated with it.

A few advices though :

- If you add [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) as a dependency in your project, Picasso will automagically add network caching. Cached images load faster and less data consumption.
- To use just the memory you need, I would resize the images to match the ImageView size. To do that, use : 
  `Picasso.with(context).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);`

Comment: Ah, I thought it would, but it seems that earlier I was using a different approach to the view paging where the fragments were not destroyed correctly. After that, there was an exceptionally large image that caused the out-of-memory error. Resizing the images works perfectly. Thanks!